# APA6 Figure caption not italic

Tags: floats, captions, apa6

For my thesis, I want to apply APA6 Table and Figure captions correctly, like on this screenshot:  [image]

It works perfectly for my table captions, however the figure captions are wrong, as the number of the Figure is displayed in italic (see screenshot). [image]

I will paste the preamble of my document here. I tried to fix the issue with `\captionsetup[figure]` but it does not work. I guess it has something to do with the document class apa6, but I do not understand why it works for the tables but not for the figure. I am very thankful for any help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,floatsintext,twoside]{apa6}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf}, textfont={it},format=plain,justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=10pt, name={\textup{Figure}}}
  
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf},textfont={it},format=plain,justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=10pt}


\doublespacing

\begin{document}



And then the figure:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{\label{fig:H2_plot.jpeg}XXX}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{H2_plot.jpeg}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting your whole preamble, it's more helpful to condense your code into a small self-contained document that shows the problem.  BTW, you shouldn't be using `utf8x` (see [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067)) and you should generally load `hyperref` last in package loading. You're also loading packages that aren't designed to be used together (`appendix` and `titlesec`) and you're loading packages multiple times.

Comment: Where did you get the screenshot from? I looked through the official website (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/tables-figures/figures)  and  it seems you got the screenshot from there. Please note that this website describes the APA7 style. The style of figure and table captions seem to  have changed from APA6 to APA7, so infact, you seem to want to use `\documentclass{apa7}` instead.

Comment: So look at APA6.cls or APA7.cls and copy the definition of \@makecaption (adding \makeatletter and \makeatother).